# Large Anti JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a training database and I am trying to find the best way to create a list of all the users and all the classes they HAVEN'T taken. I have two tables a courses master table of 150 classes and a registration table that is 175K. I can create an anti join for a single person:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblCourses  C --150 rows
Left JOIN tblTraineeCourses TC -- 175K
    ON C.CourseId = TC.CourseId AND TraineeId = 2283539
WHERE TC.CourseID IS  NULL
```

And an Anti Join to see what classes have never been taken

```
SELECT *
FROM tblCourses  C --150 rows
Left JOIN tblTraineeCourses TC 
     ON C.CourseId = TC.CourseId --175K
WHERE TC.CourseID IS  NULL
```

but i am looking for a way to produce a list table of every User ID and the classes they haven't taken.

I fully realize that this will produce a massive table but I need to do it for an analysis

Comment: I don't like anti joins that much, as they are less readable as the straight-forward queries with `NOT IN`or `NOT EXISTS` in my opinion. As Gordon says in his answer: First get all combinations of users and courses with a cross join. Then I'd use `EXCEPT` which I consider the most readable here. `NOT IN` would be my second choice (`where (t.traineeid, c.courseid) not in (...)`. `NOT EXISTS` would come third for me and I'd only use an anti join in case my DBMS' optimizer did a very poor job and came up with a bad execution plan for the aforementioned methods.

Comment: When asking SQL questions here, you should always tag your request with the DBMS you are using. Which is it? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: Good Call is it is SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate all combinations.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
SELECT T.TraineeId, C.CourseId
FROM tblTrainees t CROSs JOIN
     tblCourses  C LEFT JOIN
     tblTraineeCourses TC 
     ON TC.CourseId = C.CourseId AND
        TC.TraineeId = T.TraineeId
WHERE TC.CourseID IS NULL;
```

This assumes that you have a list of trainees, in `tblTrainees`.  You could replace that with:

```
(SELECt DISTINCT TraineeId FROM tblTraineeCourses
) t
```

If you don't have such a table.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!